# How to refresh selectors with different id at the same time?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to refresh two selectors with diffrent id at the same time as show below ?

```
$('#select-choice-direction #select-choice-direction-postuser').html(xmlhttp.responseText).selectmenu( "refresh");
```

Comment: `'#select-choice-direction, #select-choice-direction-postuser'` Try a comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a comma to separate them. What you're doing there instead is finding children with ID `select-choice-direction-postuser` that have `select-choice-direction` as a parent.

Should be changed to:

```
$('#select-choice-direction, #select-choice-direction-postuser').html();
```